# How to setup a proxy inside Grunt.js based ember-app-kit?

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I need a proxy to interact with some external APIs during development. I fumbled around with [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy), but beeing a Grunt noobie, i failed getting it to work inside [ember-app-kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit)'s Gruntfile or options/connect.js file.

Assuming that needing a proxy in development would be a rather common task, can somebody show an example of how to setup a proxy inside ember-app-kit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have installed grunt-connect-proxy (`npm install grunt-connect-proxy --save-dev`)

In Gruntfile.js add 'configureProxies' before 'connect:server' in the test:server and server tasks

```
grunt.registerTask('server', "Run your server in development mode, auto-rebuilding when files change.",
                 ['build:debug', 'configureProxies', 'connect:server', 'watch:main']);
```

Add the following to taskRequirements in tasks/helpers.js

```
'connectProxy': ['grunt-connect-proxy']
```

In tasks/options/connect.js add the proxy settings on the same level as your server settings

```
// example settings to proxy to a dev server
proxies: [{
  context: '/api',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 7000,
  changeOrigin: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}],
```

In the same file, add the following to require the proxyRequest in the middleware function

```
if (Helpers.isPackageAvailable("grunt-connect-proxy")) {
  result.splice(1,0, require("grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils").proxyRequest);
}
```

See https://gist.github.com/jfranz/7034552 for a more complete example.

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer, jfranz.Short addition: For targeting hosts via HTTPS i had to specify the correct port (443).

  proxies: [{
    context: '/example',
    host: 'www.example.com',
    port: 443,
    https: true,
    rewrite: { '^/example': '' }…

Comment: I'm still unable to get this to work, Is there some way of showing debug information in the configureProxies task?